# compare and append two dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe where df1 have header request ID and df2 have header request ID.
I wanted to check df1 header request ID in df2, if there is df2 have same request ID as same as df1 header request ID, then append it.

> df1 = [{'GUID': 'login',
> 'sent': True,
> 'Header Request': '2671257824',
> 'count': 314},
> {'GUID': 'login',
> 'sent': True,
> 'Header Request': '2700603520',
> 'count': 441}]

> df2 = [{'GUID': 'Res',
> 'sent': False,
> 'Header Request': '2671257824',
> 'count': 318},
> {'GUID': 'Res',
> 'sent': False,
> 'Header Request': '2700603520',
> 'count': 445}
> ]

> df3 = [{'GUID': 'login',
> 'sent': True,
> 'Header Request': '2671257824',
> 'count': 314},
> {'GUID': 'Res',
> 'sent': False,
> 'Header Request': '2671257824',
> 'count': 318},
> {'GUID': 'login',
> 'sent': True,
> 'Header Request': '2700603520',
> 'count': 441},
> {'GUID': 'Res',
> 'sent': False,
> 'Header Request': '2700603520',
> 'count': 445}

]

df1 =
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59f4E.png)

df2 =
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TJ8V.png)

output should like this
df3 =
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKJCM.png)

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', left_on='Header Request')

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a left join then

`df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on='Header Request')`

Comment: tried it but its not appending rows instead its appending all columns

Comment: I can't test without example code, it's poor practice to post images but something like this might work

`pd.concat(df1, df2[df2['Header Request'].isin(df1['Header Request'])])`

Comment: pd.concat(df1, df2[df2['Header Request'].isin(df1['Header Request'])]) --> Its not working 

TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"

Comment: Try this then

`.......isin(df1['Header Request']).drop_duplicates().to_list())])`

Comment: ValueError: Item wrong length 2 instead of 145.

Comment: Realised I missed some brackets `pd.concat([df1, df2[df2['Header Request'].isin(df1['Header Request'])]])`